# Copy Grid record to another Grid

Tags: gridview, extjs, jsonstore

I have a grid that using jsonstore using ajax proxy with json reader.

Now I am trying to copy one of the selected record using cellclick on the 1st grid. Lets say I am clicked on 12341 and I want the output as GRID 2

GRID:1

```
ANO          ANAME
------------------
12345        XXXXXX
12341        XXXXXX (selected)
```

GRID: 2

```
ANO          ANAME
------------------
12341        XXXXXX (selected)
```

I have tried with grid2.getStore().loadData(record) but its not reflecting as the Grid 2 is also using a jsonStore.

Appreciate your help !!

Comment: Add method working :      Ext.getCmp('grid2').getStore().add(record.data);

Answer (score 0):

```
grid1.getStore().remove([record]);
grid2.getStore().add([record]);
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks Reimius it worked when i used (record.data) not working with (record)

Comment: @aswininayak That is because the record knows the store it is bound to. I think that is the reason why it want work. If you only suplly the data the store will create a new record which is then bound to that store.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show exactly how I do it in my code.  This should move the actual record object, not create a new one based on the previous one's data.